# Operating on list elements : Haskell

Tags: haskell

I used break to split a string. Now I want to operate on the elements that have been split. How can i do that?
This is the code I used to break the string :
    print $ (break (== ' ') comm)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type signature of `break` (when used with strings) is:

```
break :: (Char -> Bool) -> String -> (String, String)
```

so `break (== ' ') comm` is a tuple of strings `(before,match)` where `before` is the part before the first match and `match` is the rest.

To use, just assign the result of the `break` to a tuple:

```
main = do
    comm <- getLine
    let (before,after) = break (== ' ') comm
    putStrLn $ "before the first space: " ++ before
    putStrLn $ "after = " ++ after
```